# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256

Tags: swift

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let dataURLString: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "IMG_0568", ofType: "JPG")!
    let dataURL = URL(string: dataURLString)
    do {
        let binaryData = try Data(contentsOf: dataURL!, options: [])
        let kbData = binaryData.subdata(in: 0..<1024)
        let stringArray = kbData.map{String(format: "%02X", $0)}
        let binaryString = stringArray.joined(separator: "-")
        print(binaryString)
        editorTextView.text = (binaryString)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to read the file.")
        //Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “IMG_0568.JPG” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=/Users/..../IMG_0568.JPG}
    }
```

I want to display the Binary Data of Image File that I have added to my Xcode project (image name: `IMG_0568.JPG`).

But there's the error

> (Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “IMG_0568.JPG”
>   couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=/Users/..../IMG_0568.JPG})

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very common mistake:

URLs in the file system must be initialized with `URL(fileURLWithPath`

```
let dataURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dataURLString)
```

The difference is:

- `URL(fileURLWithPath` expects a path starting with a slash like `/Users/myUser/file.ext`
- `URL(string` expects an URL string including the **scheme** like `file:///Users...` or `http://example.com`

---

However you can avoid the mistake by using the URL related API of `Bundle`

```
let dataURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "IMG_0568", withExtension: "JPG")!
```

Comment: your explanation was very helpful @vadian !